# Use XML to specify elements of a ListView (or other similar component)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, listview, android-2.2-froyo

The Android documentation implies that I should prefer to use XML when declaring the UI: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Regardless of whether you agree that it implies this, my personal preference *is* to use XML when possible.

However, for ListView the documentation only explains how to populate it programmatically: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

How do I, say, create a ListView with three elements using only the XML layout file? Is this impossible or undesirable?

Being used to developing for the Desktop, I am not accustomed to being required to manually create elements of UI containers, so I am confused as to whether I am missing something or things are different in Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ListView and similar Views will, in general, receive data coming from a dynamic source (like a SQLite database). In that case, the only way to populate it is programmatically.

However, if you have a static list of elements, you can populate it via XML with the following attribute: android:entries. The value would be an array resource.

Example:

```
<ListView 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:entries="@array/your_array"
/>
```

Comment: How do I define `your_array`? (No, I do not need a SQL database, the data is not going to be dynamic.)

Comment: Check the doc: [String Array](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray)

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` uses `ListAdapter` which provide a `View` for each Item in `ListView`. The **template** for this item view you can very well define as another XML layout. As far as data is concerned, you can place it in an XML file in `res/values` folder as a String Array etc. Or even parse from some other file.

A totally hardcoded layout will that be of a `LinearLayout` placed inside a `ScrollView`. Then you can add many child elements to `LinearLayout`.